# applicationDidTimeout inconsistent

Tags: ios, xcode

Following [this tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/09/19/timing-out-an-application-due-to-inactivity/), I have set my iPad app to time out after half an hour.

This works perfectly running on via Xcode on the simulator or an iPad connected to the Mac. However, if I disconnect the iPad from the Mac and log back into my app, it no longer times out.

I was hoping someone might be able to shed some light on why this happens.

AppDelegate.m

```
-(void)applicationDidTimeout:(NSNotification *) notif
{
    NSLog (@"time exceeded!!");

    UIViewController *controller = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainView"];

    [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

TIMERUIApplication.h

```
@interface TIMERUIApplication : UIApplication
{
    NSTimer     *myidleTimer;
}

-(void)resetIdleTimer;
```

TIMERUIApplication.m

```
-(void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super sendEvent:event];

    if (!myidleTimer)
    {
        [self resetIdleTimer];
    }

    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    if ([allTouches count] > 0)
    {
        UITouchPhase phase = ((UITouch *)[allTouches anyObject]).phase;
        if (phase == UITouchPhaseBegan)
        {
            [self resetIdleTimer];
        }

    }
 }
-(void)resetIdleTimer
{
     if (myidleTimer)
    {
        [myidleTimer invalidate];
    }
    int timeout = kApplicationTimeoutInMinutes * 60;
    myidleTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeout target:self selector:@selector(idleTimerExceeded) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}

-(void)idleTimerExceeded
{
    isLoggedIn = FALSE;
    numberOfFIlesAlreadyDownloaded = 0;
    numberOfFilesToBeDownloaded = 0;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]  postNotificationName:kApplicationDidTimeoutNotification object:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some further experimenting narrowed this down a bit to the iPad Auto-Lock.

When the iPad goes to sleep, so does the app, meaning the timer is interrupted.

Connecting the iPad to the Mac disabled auto-lock, which was why I only noticed it on a disconnected iPad.